# Android Fetch Internet Data

Tags: android, database, android-studio, web-scraping

I'm just starting out in android and I'm trying to build a test app that fetches data from a couple of different websites and returns that data to a database that I can filter and search. This data will not be from an RSS feed. The only thing I've seen that could do this is some type of web scraper. Can I use a web scraper in the app or do I need to take a different route?

Comment: Why is this too broad? There are only a couple of options as to web scraping that I know of. If I view the page source it has a <p class = "name". I need to be able to scrape all of them that are located inside the <p class = "name". Then I need to put them in a database, so that i can search for them. Is jsoup a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

this maybe what you are looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92p6noZjRbk&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvQUjiCc8lUT9aO0GsWA4uNe&index=9

Derek Bannas makes great tutorials to learn languages

Comment: Derek Banas is great. I have watched some of his tutorials before. I'm not sure if this is the route I would take though, since this uses the yahoo developer console. Basically I'm trying to build a location based app, but everything I've found doesn't have enough options that I can gather for sorting this information. Therefore, somehow I've got to gather the data and add extra queries.